# Auto Layout view resizing Through XIB in xcode 5

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have an `UIView` in "XIB" using xcode 5 which is resized during runtime. I took "center X" and "center Y" constraints along with width and height constraints having relation greater than or equals. Doing so ambiguity error is shown.

My question is how to use these `>=` constraints and if orange lines shows i.e: some error then how to resolve this error,

Is this error here in case normal or this can be resolved?
I want to solve this problem by "XIB" only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably, the best way of approaching this problem is to reset to suggested constrains, and start from that point.

The >= constrain indicates that you can have a bigger value, for example stretch a screen in a mac app, but you cannot go below that given number.

Orange lines doesn't mean necessarily an error, it may indicate that more constrains are needed. You may want to read this [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html).